# Oracle returns an error ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: linux, oracle

Oracle returns an error "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges"
When I run `sqlplus / as sysdba` but `sqlplus sys/oracle123 as sysdba` doesn't, why?

- Oracle version: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - 64bit
- Linux version: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)

I know that Oracle uses OS authentication when running `sqlplus / as sysdba`, I also checked sqlnet.ora carefully and it contains `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)`.

I also changed the oracle user's group, oracle user absolutely belongs to dba group because when I run command id the following information returns:

```
oracle@linux-mage:~> id
uid=103(oracle) gid=106(dba) groups=105(oinstall),106(dba)
```

Another information is I can logged on through `sqlplus sys/oracle123 as sysdba`, but I can not shutdown the instance:

```
oracle@linux-mage:~> sqlplus sys/oracle123 as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Sep 5 16:29:57 2011

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected.
SQL> shutdown immediate
ORA-24324: service handle not initialized
ORA-24323: value not allowed
ORA-27140: attach to post/wait facility failed
SQL> shutdown abort
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
SQL>
```

i ran strace -o trace.out sqlplus "/ as sysdba" and get the following output message.
the strace message is too big. so i paste it into pastebin. please visit this link

http://pastebin.com/YpjVeG8u

ipcs -s and ipcs -ls information:
    oracle@linux-mage:~> ipcs -s

```
------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems

oracle@linux-mage:~> ipcs -ls

------ Semaphore Limits --------
max number of arrays = 200
max semaphores per array = 250
max semaphores system wide = 32000
max ops per semop call = 100
semaphore max value = 32767
```

Comment: Are you logged on as the oracle user in linux?

Comment: yes, i logged on the server computer as oracle user.

Answer (score 1):

Something must have gone wrong at the O/S level - check [this page](http://askdba.org/weblog/2008/05/ora-1031-as-sysdba/) for some steps to track down the problem

Answer (score 0):

Post/wait is the [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) IPC subsystem - it is likely that either you have run out of semaphores, or the semaphores have been created with permissions that don't permit your user to access them - check the output of `ipcs -s`, where are the permissions there? Compare the number of semaphores to `ipcs -ls`.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that once the **shutdown immediate** fails, the connection is dropped, although it doesn't show it. Exiting sqlplus, reconnecting and immediately issuing **shutdown abort** got things unstuck for me.

From https://community.oracle.com/thread/459659

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem of getting an ORA-01031 error when doing a `sqlplus / as sysdba`.  My problem was corrected when I unset the environment variable `TWO_TASK`.